# How to use FetchAll in PyPyODBC Module for Python?

Tags: python, sql-server, ipython, pypyodbc

I am trying to use [PyPyODBC](https://code.google.com/p/pypyodbc/), specifically a take on this [example](https://code.google.com/p/pypyodbc/wiki/A_HelloWorld_sample_to_access_mssql_with_python). However, I am not interested in creating a new table, I simply want to read the data (which resides in a database/table in SQL Server) and work with it inside of Python.

The below code works fine with the exception of the following section (
`for row in cur.fetchall():`).

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pypyodbc
from  pandas import *
import pandas as pd
con = pypyodbc.connect(driver = '{SQL Server}', server = 'WIN-SAV35R5AKCQ',database ='V2.0.6_X12_837I')

cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM TS837_2400;''')
cur.commit()

for d in cur.description: 
    print (d[0], end=" ")

print('')

for row in cur.fetchall():
    for field in row: 
        print (field, end=" ")
    print ('')

cur.close()
con.close()
```

However, I get this error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-c08d5a03056a> in <module>()
     14 print('')
     15 
---> 16 for row in cur.fetchall():
     17     for field in row:
     18         print (field, end=" ")

C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.pyc in fetchall(self)
   1805         rows = []
   1806         while True:
-> 1807             row = self.fetchone()
   1808             if row is None:
   1809                 break

C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.pyc in fetchone(self)
   1900                 return None
   1901             else:
-> 1902                 check_success(self, ret)
   1903 
   1904     def __next__(self):

C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.pyc in check_success(ODBC_obj, ret)
    981     if ret not in (SQL_SUCCESS, SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO, SQL_NO_DATA):
    982         if isinstance(ODBC_obj, Cursor):
--> 983             ctrl_err(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, ODBC_obj.stmt_h, ret, ODBC_obj.ansi)
    984         elif isinstance(ODBC_obj, Connection):
    985             ctrl_err(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, ODBC_obj.dbc_h, ret, ODBC_obj.ansi)

C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.pyc in ctrl_err(ht, h, val_ret, ansi)
    959                 raise OperationalError(state,err_text)
    960             elif state[:2] in (raw_s('IM'),raw_s('HY')):
--> 961                 raise Error(state,err_text)
    962             else:
    963                 raise DatabaseError(state,err_text)

Error: (u'HY010', u'[HY010] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Function sequence error')
```

**Question:**
*Ultimately*, I want to be able to investigate the data in Python.How can this be done?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, I am using Python 2.7 (iPython). I am assumpy PyPyODBC is Version 1.3.0. Since I ran an !pip install --upgrade and it is the last version in the change log.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `cur.commit()` line, it isn't needed for a SELECT.

I was able to reproduce the error with [pyodbc](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/), so I'm assuming the same will work for pypyodbc. You should be able to apply the [pyodbc examples](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/GettingStarted) to your code, I think they are more complete than pypyodbc's current offering.